# How to install an older version of Transmission?

Tags: 11.04, installation, compiling

I want to install Transmission v2.22 in /opt in Ubuntu Natty but I do not want to remove the new version.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you download the source, you can compile it using:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt
make
sudo make install
```